# Getting access denied while accessing the sqs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sqs

Getting the message -
MessageAccessDenied: Access to the resource https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ is denied
while sending the message to SQS from lamda function.
What i am doing wrong?

```
var QUEUE_URL = 'QUEUE_URL';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region : 'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var params = {
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(event),
    QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL
  };
  sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
    if(err) {
      console.log('error:',"Fail Send Message" + err);
      context.done('error', "ERROR Put SQS");  // ERROR with message
    }else{
      console.log('data:',data.MessageId);
      context.done(null,'');  // SUCCESS 
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion -- look at using latest JS V3 Async code as specified in the AWS GitHub repo here https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/sqs (for Lambda - make sure role has access to this service too)

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the IAM role you have assigned to the AWS Lambda function. You need to add permission to that IAM role to put messages in the SQS queue.